# Summation of specific range in a row of a 2d list in Python

Tags: python, list, sum, 2d

I have a 2d list, say a `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]]`. I know that I can get summation of first row by `sum(a[0])`. But what if I need summation of first two or three items. The pseudocode should be like this:
`sum(a[0,1:N]) == 0` which means summation of 1 to N elements in row 0.

Comment: Can you use additional packages? I'd recommend looking into pandas if so.

Comment: so, the answer would be 6 if N=3 in the given example? try: `sum(a[0][:N])`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Panda but I will take a look at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear either you want sum your first index ie sum of the a[0] = 1+2+3+4 = 10

code for above

```
sum = 0
for value in a[0]:
    sum = sum + value

print sum
```

If you want sum of all element till N ie 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 =45

lenth_of_array =len(a)

sum = 0

```
for i, array in enumerate(a):
    for value in array[i]:
        sum = sum + value

print sum
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. sum(a[0][0:3]) already handle the task.

Answer (score 1):

slicing a list of lists requires iterated slicing, not indexing

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]] 

sum(a[0][0:3])
```

> 6

which is 1 + 2 + 3 (the first 3 elements of a; remember python uses half-open intervals)

Comment: Even more close to the question: `sum(a[0][:2])` or `sum(a[0][:3])`.

Comment: Works well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
ll = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]]

def getSum(list_index,count):
  # list_index = index of list.
  # count = tuple , first and last index
  return sum(ll[list_index][count[0]:count[1]+1])

result = getSum(0,(1,3))
print(result)

# getSum(0,(1,2))
# 0 = > list_index => [1,2,3,4]
# (1,2) => element (1 to 3) => 2 + 3 + 4 = 9
```

Comment: this is kind of overkill, isn't it?

Comment: I think so although it is a wise way. sum(a[0][:2]) already solve the problem.